# Maps API v3 Get closest place within radius if Geocoder returns ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get a formatted user address using `Geolocation API` and `Google Maps Geocoder`. It all works fine, but not in every place. For example, [my address](https://www.google.com/maps/place/42%C2%B038'46.5%22N+21%C2%B010'42.6%22E/@42.6462549,21.1779498,19z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d42.6462539!4d21.1784983) with latitude`42.6462539 21.178498299999998` returns `ZERO_RESULTS`... If you check the map, the area around those coordinates has fairly enough data, so is it possible to get an approximate address, say the closest road or place, within a given radius, e.g. 250m

Here's my current code:

```
if (!navigator.geolocation) alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    geocoder.geocode({latLng: latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            console.log('Geocoding successful.', results);
        } else {
            console.log('Geocoding failed...', status);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoding doesn't seem to work in your area, even with other nearby coordinates. You could check for the status and use another way to find the nearest place.

```
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    // Success

} else if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

    // Try something else
}
```

One solution would be for example the [Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest?hl=en). With your example coordinates, it works.

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=42.6462539,21.178498299999998&key=your_api_key
```

You will have to enable the API in your Google developer console and provide your own key.

The above query returns:

```
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 42.646445887532415,
        "longitude": 21.178424485523163
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJwzaWjcieVBMR-DmaAxrqIs8"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 42.646445887532415,
        "longitude": 21.178424485523163
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJwzaWjcieVBMR-TmaAxrqIs8"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then with the returned `placeId`

```
geocoder.geocode({
  'placeId': 'ChIJwzaWjcieVBMR-DmaAxrqIs8'
  }, function (results, status) {

    // Returns "Muharrem Fejza, Prishtinë"
});
```

You could also try with a [nearby search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#PlacesService), depends what you aim for. The nearby search accepts a radius parameter.

Comment: The nearby search method did it. Thanks!